# Inquiry Regarding Feasibility of Fetching User login hours(In numbers) Status from Teams for SPFx Integration

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am reaching out to inquire about the feasibility of integrating user status information from Microsoft Teams into our SharePoint Framework (SPFx) solution.
As we strive to enhance collaboration and communication within our organization, we believe that having real-time visibility into users' availability statuses hours (such as available, away, busy, in a call, out of office hours) directly within our SharePoint environment could greatly improve productivity and streamline workflow processes.

Could anyone please provide insight into whether it is possible to access and retrieve user status information from Teams programmatically? Additionally, we are interested in understanding any potential challenges or limitations associated with implementing such functionality within SPFx.
Your expertise in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graph `/presence` method. User presence is not "in teams", it is sort of "global" (i.e. you can see it also in Outlook or Excel for example).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

In the SPFx web part:

```
 this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then(async (client) => {
   const presence = await client.api(`users/${userId}/presence`)
   // do something with the presence
 }
```

Here I came across some article that explains that in details:
https://vitalyzhukov.com/en/spfx-teams-presence-status-microsoft-graph

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.
With the above link and http call, I could retrieve the live status of the user, but not the hours.
I am trying to fetch the user hours spent on available, away, busy, in-a-call, and out-of-office hours in numbers.

Comment: I see. No idea how to do that, or if it is possible at all (I think not, because it looks more like spying after people). To track people timing/office hours, it's better to install some tracking app.